# Best method for calculating all correlations in a dataset?

Tags: correlation

First of all, to be clear, I don't want *all* correlations in the dataset, I just want to find all high correlations between the response variable and the features.

I posted this question to reddit on 'learnmachinelearning' and 'MLQuestions' but I've received no responses. Is the question malformed? Perhaps nobody knows how to do what I thought seemed like a simple task for a statistician?

https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmachinelearning/comments/quey2j/simple_question_from_novice_about_correlation/

You can go to the link and read the original question, or you can read the simplified version here:
My dataset is one hot encoded with a bunch of features, each row an observation. The response variable has several buckets.

| Feature1 | F2 | F3 | ... | Response Variable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | ... | X |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | ... | Y |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

How do I produce a dataset which shows the count of observations (or % of time) that the response variable was each value for every set of feature values, like this one:

| Response Variable | F1=1 | ...each other feature... | F1=1, F2=1 | ...all other feature combinations... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 100 % (of the time) | ... | 0 % | ... |
| Y | 29 % | ... | 1% | ... |
| ...all values... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Does this kind of calculation have a name? is this built into any packages? must I merely calculate it manually in pandas (I usually use python)?

Furthermore, if I wanted to also calculate confidence for each, how would I go about doing that?

Thank you for your guidance!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “correlation” involving a categorical variable?

Comment: @Dave I mean, I want to know things like "everytime Feature 1 is 'present' the Response Variable is X" that is, feature 1 has a strong correlation with response variable X. perhaps, however, half the times feature 1 is present, response variable is Y. What if, every time Features 1, 4 and 10 are present the response variable is X, otherwise its quite chaotic, I want to know that too. calculating it all out, for all combinations should give me those insights.